# C# Get value and name of all properties of type bool

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the name and value of all the properties where it's type is bool, seems to be working but getting the wrong value.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
signupItem.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && (bool) p.GetValue(signupItem, null))
    .Select(p => p.Name).ToList().ForEach(prop => {

    var value = (Boolean) signupItem.GetType()
    .GetProperty(prop).GetValue(signupItem, null);

    html = (value) ?
        html.Replace("{chkbox}", "<input type='checkbox' id='html' checked>") :
        html.Replace("{chkbox}", "<input type='checkbox' id='html'>");
    });
```

Example:
here - Value comes as true
[image: Value should be true]

But it shows false when trying to assign it to a variable.

[image: Value shows as false]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must proceed one more step in the debugger in order for the assignment to be carried out.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning false? It looks like you're still on the breakpoint and thus the value hasn't been assigned yet. Hit f10 and see if it's still false

Comment: My bad you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. don't use `.ForEach()`
2. you are selecting the *name* of each property when you should be using the properties themselves:
3. You are using the same `html` value for each iteration, so the first loop will replace ALL `{chkbox}` values.

try this:

```
var properties = signupItem.GetType()
                           .GetProperties()
                           .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
                                    && (bool) p.GetValue(signupItem, null));


foreach (Property prop in properties) {
    // don't you already know this is true from the `Where` clause?
    var value = (Boolean) prop.GetValue(signupItem, null);

    // this only happens for the first item - for all other items "{chkbox}" will already be replaced.
    html = (value) ?
        html.Replace("{chkbox}", "<input type='checkbox' id='html' checked>") :
        html.Replace("{chkbox}", "<input type='checkbox' id='html'>");
}
```

Comment: @KennethK It requires an unneccessary call to `ToList()` and add no value other than the idiomatic `foreach` loop. Also, read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: Then I guess Skeet (et al.) [felt compelled](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#foreach) to heed the last paragraph. Point taken, though.

Comment: @KennethK. It can also make debugging more difficult, since the loop is not executed until the query is actually enumerated, which _might_ be part of the OP's problem. As I comment, though, there are other suspicious things with the code.

Comment: I know that it will replace all the checkboxes, I'll add the property name to fix that, I just needed to have the other part working, but yeah, I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Sure. I was more intrigued by the imperativeness of your statement.